# What is this program supposed to do?

Tags: javascript

Can anyone explain to me why this program doesn't work ?

```
function powerf(base,exp){

    if(exp==1)
       return 1;

    if(exp % 2 == 0)    
       return powerf(base,exp/2);

    else 
       return 2*powerf(base,exp-2); 
}
```

Comment: what is it suppose to do?

Comment: WHat is not working?

Comment: this program should return the value of power like this 
for example : powerf(2,3) ==> 8
but when i run it the result is powerf(2,3)==> 2

Comment: When exp is 1 you should return base, not 1. Return 1 when exp is 0

Comment: I try this one and also the result wrong 
 


function powerf(base,exp){

   if(exp===1){   

    return base; 

     } 

    if(exp===0){

     return 1;
    } 
    if(exp % 2 === 0){
    return powerf(base,exp/2); 
     }  
     else   
          return  2*powerf(base,exp-2); 
         }

Comment: function powerf(base,exp){
   if(exp===1){   
    return base; 
     } 
    if(exp===0){
     return 1;
    } 
    if(exp % 2 === 0){
    return powerf(base,exp/2); 
     }  
     else   
          return  2*powerf(base,exp-2); 
         }

Answer (score 0):

use this code :

```
    <body>
    <p id="x"></p>
    <script>
        function powerf(base, exp) {
         var result = 1;
         while(exp--) {
        result *= base;
        }
  return result;
}
        document.getElementById("x").innerHTML = powerf(2,3);
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

> this program should return the value of power like this for example :
>   powerf(2,3) ==> 8 but when i run it the result is powerf(2,3)==> 2

This is because, when you say `powerf(2,3)`, it goes to last `else` section and it becomes

`powerf(2,3)` -> `2*power(2,1)` -> `2*1` (since anything raise to power 1 is 1 as per your logic)

Why not simply have

```
function powerf(base, exp)
{ 
  return Math.pow(base, exp);
}
```

Comment: Because I have to solve this program without using Math.pow :)
I should use recursion

Comment: @maryam can the `exp` be an exponential or negative value? in that case you need to design logic for all those scenarios as well.